# For Laravel Project is it possible to assign another back up server?

Tags: database, laravel, server

I am running a laravel project, i have backed up the data from the database to a second database. in case if the first database goes down how to configure the second database to be used.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#configuration

Comment: Laravel still doesn't seem to have such a feature for failover by default. 

The above link mentioned by @Jerodev uses read-write servers where one server is used for all read operations and another for write operations. It doesn't make your app fully function if one goes down. 

However, if you have enough resources you can configure master/slave configuration of your database and use a load balancer in front to distribute the database traffic to both database servers.

Answer (score 1):

Change the .env information

```
DB_DATABASE = YOUR_NEW_DATABASE
```

```
php artisan config:clear
```